# install latest node version in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, npm, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile

```yaml
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

RUN apk add --update nodejs; \
    apk add --update npm;

RUN npm cache clean -f; \
    npm install n -g; \
    n stable; \
    npm update -g; \
    npm install npm@latest -g;

RUN npm install koa --save; \
    npm install koa-router --save; \
    npm install dotenv --save; \
    npm install koa-cors --save; \
    npm install pm2 --save;
```

and get error messages:

> npm notice  npm notice New patch version of npm available! 8.1.0 ->
> 8.1.2 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.1.2 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.1.2` to update! npm notice  env: can't execute
> 'bash': No such file or directory npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0:
> Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use
> Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be
> problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

Comment: Why dont you use the offical node.js image?

Comment: @Marc what you mean? node:alpine is official node image

Comment: Most probably you have an old image, try to re-download the image. `docker pull node:alpine`

Comment: @Max no. I am trying to build an image on a completely clean system - node: alpine download from the hub for every docker build